# How to combine Date_format and Date_sub

Tags: mysql, date, date-format, intervals

I want to subtract one year 2 months and 5 days from the current date but I'm trying to print it out in a different formate. Instead of it combining it is printing out 2 different things

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%W, %M %d, %Y, %h:%i%p'),DATE_Sub(DATE_Sub(Date_Sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 2   year), INTERVAL 2 month), Interval 5 day);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are printing two strings, the first one applies your date_format to NOW() and the second does the calculations, but doesn't apply the date_format.

Maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(
  DATE_Sub(
    DATE_Sub(
      Date_Sub(
        NOW(), 
        INTERVAL 2 year), 
      INTERVAL 2 month), 
    Interval 5 day), 
  '%W, %M %d, %Y, %h:%i%p'
);
```

Output:

```
Tuesday, August 21, 2012, 03:58PM
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/47235)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `date_sub()` to get the right date/time:

```
select date_sub(date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 1 year), interval 2 month), interval 2 day)
```

or

```
select date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 14 month), interval 2 day)
```

And then use `date_format()` to get it in whatever format you want:

```
select date_format(date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 14 month), interval 2 day), '%W, %M %d, %Y, %h:%i%p')
```